# Firebase storage cant upload files with button

Tags: javascript

```
var file;

/////detect if file is upload/////////

$("#file").on('change',function(e){
    file = e.target.files[0];       

});
/////function for upload to storage button when clicked///////////
function uploadFile(){
    var storageRef = firebase.storage().ref('/pics/'+file.name);
    var task = storageRef.put(file);

    console.log("yes");
}
```

Comment: What is your error?

Comment: "can't" isn't an error message or problem statement. No one can fix "can't". Please add some text to your question which clarifies the exact issue you're experiencing. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for further guidance on asking a good-quality, useful question. Thanks.

Comment: @KingStone when i put storage ref and task inside the onChange function it works, but not inside the uploadFile() function. I just want to save the files after the user click submit.(else if user want to choose different image for their profile they would have many images in the storage)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On my side, below code is working well, and that is almost the same as the question code.

```
<html>
<header>
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.6.0/firebase.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
  <script>

    var config = {
      apiKey: "                                 ",
      authDomain: "                             ",
      databaseURL: "                            ",
      projectId: "                              ",
      storageBucket: "                          ",
      messagingSenderId: "                      "
    };
    firebase.initializeApp(config);

    $(document).ready(function () {
      var file;

      $("#file").on('change', function (e) {
        file = e.target.files[0];
      });

      $('#btnUpload')
        .click(function () {
          if (file == null || file.name == null) {
            alert("Please select file");
            return;
          }
          var storageRef = firebase.storage().ref('/pics/' + file.name);
          var task = storageRef.put(file)
            .then((snapshot) => {
              console.log('Uploaded a blob or file!', snapshot);
            })
            .catch(error => {
              console.error(error)
            });
        });
    });

  </script>
</header>

<body>
  <h3>Upload File</h3>
  <div>
    <input type="file" id="file" class="form">
    <button class="btn btn-danger" id="btnUpload">Upload</button>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

**Updated:**
Only added `then`, `catch` for debug.
But, working well.

```
var task = storageRef.put(file)
            .then((snapshot) => {
              console.log('Uploaded a blob or file!', snapshot);
            })
            .catch(error => {
              console.error(error)
            });
```

Comment: I tried those kind of placement before but it didn't work. Somehow you make it works. Thanks man!